# How to change the handleChange action based on the select input using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, onchange

I have some handleChange actions need to be selected, when selected it will fire the selected handleChange action, below is the code:

handleChange action:

```
handleEqualChange(event){
this.setState({
  equal: event.target.value,
 });
}

handleNotEqualChange(event){
this.setState({
  notequal: event.target.value,
 });
}

handleGreaterThanChange(event){
this.setState({
  greater_than: event.target.value,
 });
}

handleSmallerThanChange(event){
this.setState({
  smaller_than: event.target.value,
 });
}

handleGOEChange(event){
this.setState({
  goe: event.target.value,
 });
}

handleLOEChange(event){
this.setState({
  loe: event.target.value,
 });
}
```

The dropdown menu select option:

```
<select>
 <option value={this.state.equal}>Equal to</option>
 <option value={this.state.notequal}>Not equal to</option>
 <option value={this.state.greater_than}>Greater than</option>
 <option value={this.state.smaller_than}>Less than</option>
 <option value={this.state.goe}>Greater than or equal to</option>
 <option value={this.state.loe}>Less than or equal to</option>
</select>
```

The text input:

```
<input className="col-md-1" type="text" placeholder="10" 
value={this.state.greater_than} onChange={this.handleGreaterThanChange} required/>
```

I want to pass the value of the text input to the redux action but it always return as {this.state.greater_than} value, I want to like when select {this.state.smaller_than} in the option then it will pass the {this.state.smaller_than} value and fire the {this.handleSmallerThanChange} action, may I know how to do that? Thank you.

The redux action I do like this:

```
export function createEvents(id, equal, notequal, greater_than, smaller_than, goe: goe, loe: loe, topic, email, contact) {
return (dispatch) => { // optionally you can have getState as the second argument
dispatch({
  type: EVENTS_CREATE_EVENTS_BEGIN,
});
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // doRequest is a placeholder Promise. You should replace it with your own logic.
  // See the real-word example at:  https://github.com/supnate/rekit/blob/master/src/features/home/redux/fetchRedditReactjsList.js
  // args.error here is only for test coverage purpose.
  //const doRequest = args.error ? Promise.reject(new Error()) : Promise.resolve();
  axios.get('http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/Limits?filter[where][topic]=' + topic)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data[0].id);

        axios.put('http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/Limits/' + res.data[0].id, { equal: equal, notequal: notequal, greater_than: greater_than, smaller_than: smaller_than, goe: goe, loe: loe, topic: topic, email: email, contact: contact }, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(
          (res) => {
            dispatch({
              type: EVENTS_CREATE_EVENTS_SUCCESS,
              data: res,
            });
            resolve(res);
            //window.location = '/events/events-page';
          },
          // Use rejectHandler as the second argument so that render errors won't be caught.
          (err) => {
            dispatch({
              type: EVENTS_CREATE_EVENTS_FAILURE,
              data: { error: err },
            });
            reject(err);
          },
        );
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

return promise;
};
}
```

The handleChange action modified:

```
handleChange(event){
console.log("Event.target.value is", event.target.value);
 this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value});
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="equal"){
   this.setState({equal: event.target.value});
  };
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="notequal"){
   this.setState({notequal: event.target.value});
  };
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="greater_than"){
   this.setState({greater_than: event.target.value});
  };
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="smaller_than"){
   this.setState({smaller_than: event.target.value});
  };
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="goe"){
   this.setState({goe: event.target.value});
  };
  if(this.state.selectedOption=="loe"){
   this.setState({loe: event.target.value});
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not handling the select correctly. Why your options values are in the state? Your select has not an event handler and what's the select value? Why do you have an input with only handleGreaterThanChange?

However, what you have to do is to put in the state the selected value and let the select handle the change on the option selected.

Here's the code:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedOption:"equal"
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    console.log("Event.target.value is", event.target.value);

    this.setState({selectedOption:event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
       <select value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}>
         <option value={"equal"}>Equal to</option>
         <option value={"notequal"}>Not equal to</option>
         <option value={"greater_than"}>Greater than</option>
         <option value={"smaller_than"}>Less than</option>
         <option value={"goe"}>Greater than or equal to</option>
         <option value={"loe"}>Less than or equal to</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can try it with [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLounp7f/1/).

Comment: I have tried your code but it didn't pass the this.state.greater value to the redux action, it was become undefined in the redux page.

Comment: If you want to pass the selected value to redux you need to dispatch the action to redux. This is not part of your code. Probably you need to study Redux :)

Comment: I have updated with the code with redux action page here, may I know what is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: When you call createEvents you have to pass an id and the selectedOption. But.. Can you log something inside your function and inside the axios get? Does it work? Does it log something?

Comment: It only change the selectedOptions value to the database but what I want is when select smaller_than it will insert smaller_than value, when choose greater_than it will insert greater_than value and so on.

Comment: it only has the selectedOption value but other like greater_than value it is undefined

Comment: Implement some logic based on selectedOption value. I don't know how it's your database and how is structured your backend. I think that no one here could help you without basic infos.

Comment: I have modified the handleChange action and update the code in the question, I was able to pass the value to the redux action page but the problem is if I enter 35 for the greater_than value it will only enter "3" this value in the action page, may I know what is the problem with it? Thank you.